# Selenium WebDriver - Scroll inside a div (not the entire page)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Attached is how the HTML looks like:

[image: Attached is how the HTML looks like.]

I would like to scroll only inside the div, not the entire page. My aim is to scroll to the site `008 - 02 - Circleville, OH`.

Please let me know the way out.

The xpath of each site looks like below:

```
//*[@id='Sites']/div[10]
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @JeffC 
Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Will follow the guidelines next time onward. Anyways I have fixed the issue by finding the location(co-ordinates) of xpath and then scrolling into the location to make my desired xpath visible in the window.